# class and include php

Tags: php, class, include

i'm working in new project of new forums from 0 , and i want to add a nice methods and ... etc
1. first : 
i'm trying to call the class of a file in a class , i mean : 
i have a file class.php for example , and auther main.php , and index.php
in class.php i make my class, and in main.php i create auther class main , i include inside class.php , after i use a function like a class ...

class.php :

```
    <?PHP
          class test{
                   function hello(){ echo "Hello World !"; }
             }
  ?>
```

main.php

```
<?PHP
      class main{
        function _test_(){
         require_once("class.php");
         return new test();
            }
        function __destruct(){
            echo "good bye";   
          }
         }
```

index.php :

```
<?PHP
    include_once("main.php");
    $main = new main();
    $main->_test_()->hello();
    echo "<br> what !!!!???? <br>";
 ?>
```

and now the result :

```
Hello World !  
what !!!!????
good bye
```

i want to know why the class destruction did not apear after Hello World result ?? 
?>

Comment: "destruct" -- are you doing any in that script? No. So your object is not destroyed until the script starts to exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [that's how it's designed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) to be:

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other
>   references to a particular object, or **in any order during the shutdown
>   sequence**.